# Cannot convert value of type with matching types - have I hit a compiler limitation?

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, swift-protocols

Background:

I'm building an app with a service layer that should return models that are similar (e.g. all have a `text: String` property, defined in a protocol `TextModel`). The service holds a repository which finds and returns models of a concrete type conforming to `TextModel`. The repository needs to keep it's concrete type information for internal workings. I want to keep the service free from the model's concrete type so I don't have to repeat it for every model type.  The compiler isn't letting me do this...

Problem:

The following code that I have simplified in a Playground will not compile:

```
enum Result<T> {

    case success(T)
    case error
}

// Model Layer

protocol TextModel {

    var text: String { get }
}

struct Person: TextModel {

    let text: String
}

// Service Layer

class TextModelService {

    let repository: TextModelRepositoryType

    init(repository: TextModelRepositoryType) {

        self.repository = repository
    }

    func find(completion: @escaping (Result<TextModel>) -> ()) {

        repository.find(completion: completion)
    }
}

// Repository Layer

protocol TextModelRepositoryType {

    func find(completion: @escaping (Result<TextModel>) -> ())
}

protocol PersonRepositoryType {

    func findPerson(completion: @escaping (Result<Person>) -> ())
}

class PersonRepository: PersonRepositoryType, TextModelRepositoryType {

    func find(completion: @escaping (Result<TextModel>) -> ()) {

        // ERROR HERE: "Cannot convert value of type '(Result<TextModel>) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Result<Person>) -> ()'"
        findPerson(completion: completion)
    }

    func findPerson(completion: @escaping (Result<Person>) -> ()) {

        let person = Person(text: "Adam")
        completion(.success(person))
    }
}

let repository = PersonRepository()
let service = TextModelService(repository: repository)
service.find { result in

    // result should be a Result<Person>
}
```

I don't understand why the compiler states that it `'Cannot convert value of type '(Result<TextModel>) -> ()' to expected argument type '(Result<Person>) -> ()'` when `Person` definitely conforms to `TextModel`...

What's also interesting is that when I remove the `Result` type and just pass an unwrapped type in the completion (e.g. `(TextModel?) -> ()`) the compiler has no qualms.

Have I hit a limitation in the Swift compiler? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Do you _have_ to use `Result<TextModel?>`. Can `Result<TextModel>` work as well?

Comment: Done some search on "swift type variance". Turns out Swift’s generic is invariance, i.e. yes, that's how it behaves.

Comment: Sweeper, I removed the optionality from the question.

Comment: Thanks Ricky I overlooked the fact that Result<T> added generics into the equation. Thanks for the lead. I'll do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Swift has invariant generic types, `T<A>` can't be converted to `T<B>` even if `A` can be converted to `B`.

A workaround in this case is to create the conversion methods yourself:

```
enum Result<T> {

    case success(T)
    case error

    func cast<R>() -> Result<R>? {
        switch self {
        case .error: return .error
        case .success(let t) where t is R: return .success(t as! R)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
}

extension Result where T : TextModel {
    func convertToTextModel() -> Result<TextModel> {
        switch self {
        case .error: return .error
        case .success(let t): return .success(t)
        }
    }
}
```

And then call these conversion methods in `find`:

```
func find(completion: @escaping (Result<TextModel>) -> ()) {
    findPerson(completion: { completion($0.convertToTextModel()) })
}
```

and on the caller side:

```
let repository = PersonRepository()
let service = TextModelService(repository: repository)
service.find { result in
    if let person: Result<Person> = result.cast() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This worked a treat. I think my real learning here is that I have over-engineered the system in favour of testability! Thanks again.